# How to block files from access by URL

Tags: .htaccess, http, url

i have subpage like

```
mypage.com/subpage
```

But that is only alias and all files are in`/data/subpage`. And only file needed to be accessed by user himself is `index.php` and all other files are imported by index itself, depending on attributes (GET, sessions etc.)

I want this:

- Let user to access `index.php` using `/subpage` but not `/data/subpage`
- Do not let user directly access anything in `/data/subpage` and its subfolders
- still let `index.php` to access those files.

I hope I wrote it understandably.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT:** My current .htaccess (located in root)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^subpage$ /data/subpage/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^subpage/(?:([^/]+)/?|)(?:([^/]+)/?|)$ /data/subpage/index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/subpage/?(?:([^/]+)/?|)(?:([^/]+)/?|)$ /data/subpage/index.php?edit=true&section=$1&subsection=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+data/subpage/
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

so that any direct requests for `/data/subpage/` results in a 404. You can replace `R=404` with `F` if you would rather it result in a "403".

---

EDIT:

> It's kinda right, thank you. I, as a viewer, can't access those files but my page also cant access it (for ex. images). Is there any way to do it?

This isn't your *page* accessing those files, it's your page *telling the browser* to access them. That means the only way you're going to know that the page told the browser to access them is to check the referer. Unfortunately, the referer can be trivially forged so this is no guarantee that people can't get to all your files.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+data/subpage/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://yourdomain.com/subpage/(index\.php)?
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: It's kinda right, thank you. I, as a viewer, can't access those files but my page also cant access it (for ex. images). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Gomi Note that it's not your **page** that's accessing those files, it's the client's browser. It's just that your page is telling the browser to load it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't think about it properly. I've just modified it - I added the extensions of files which I really don't want to be accessed (for ex. XML files).

Thank you very much